# Self evaluation in PMP on priority basis

Tags: professionalism

My reporting manager sends a mail asking me to complete your self-evaluation in PMP on a priority basis. I am new to the company and I don't understand what is PMP. Can anyone know what he telling to do?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone know what he telling to do?

This is something you should **ask your manager to clarify**, as PMP can mean anything in your company's context.

You can also **ask a coworker** to explain to you what PMP is (if your manager is unavailable), or **see if HR has any guide or information about it** that they can share with you.